# React Native permissions read-external-storage, Read all sub-folders

Tags: react-native, permissions, nested

I'm using React-Native and I need to read a folder contains in the external storage of the phone. I also need to read all the folder inside this folder.

I am able to grant permission to the root folder using

```js
const { granted, directoryUri } = await StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();
```

But this doesnt give me access to nested folders inside the root folder. So when I try to open a subfolder I get

```
Error: Location '...' isn't readable.
```

Is there a way to grant read permission to a folder and all it's sub-file/folder in React-Native ?